# AnkhSVN on 64Bit Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, x86, 64-bit, ankhsvn

I am using [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) first time. On 32Bit Visual Studio 2010 Prof it works great.

[image]

Same installation with same project on a x64 Systems does not show the green hooks nor any SVN options. 
[image: No AnkhSVN]

It seems that it is not installed and shows all like before. Re-Installing has the same unusable effect. No errors.

I am not sure if it is because of x64 system or not.

Any ideas how it could work?

Comment: FYI: there's no such thing as a "64-bit Visual Studio"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try by changing the Source Control Provider in the Visual Studio Options
Go to  Tools -> Options -> Source Control  and change Current Source Control Plugin to AnkhSVN.

[image]

Comment: Good you made my day!! That cool. Thanks a lot for your quick reply!

Comment: @Nasenbaer - if this was the answer then mark it as the answer, don't just post another screen shot on the end of your question. (The image is good to have but it would be better in @Waleed's answer).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of swapping where the image is - regardless of who uploaded it, it is a better fit in the answer rather than tagged on the end of the question.